# Gradle: run test only when specific parameter is given

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, gradle

I want to run a specific unit test only when I am doing a PR build.
During this build I can pass a parameter eg. 'buildType' to specify that it is a PR build.

The test should never run if the buildType isn't explicitly PR build.

How could I achieve such behaviour?

Do I create separate task that I can configure this way somehow. Or do I even create another module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual exclusion will depend on what testing library you are using. For example with `JUnit5` you could do this with [tags](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering).

You would start by excluding tests tagged with `@Tag("PR")` from normal test task. Then you would define specific task such as `prTest` that also includes tests tagged with `@Tag("PR")`.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags 'PR'
    }
}

task prTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'PR'
    }
    shouldRunAfter test
}
```

Comment: Nice. I suppose that  `./gradlew prTest test` will then run prTest task after test

Comment: Yeah. Unless there are problems such as [circular dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks).